# use bootstrap accordion in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

i have to use bootstrap accordion in onepage.js. FYI, i have large amount of content which is greater than section height. Whenever i open multiples accordion, is it possible to increase the height of section.

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to change the css class:

```
.collapse.show {height: auto;  max-height: 500px /* or whatever you want /* }
```